# Create a vb class using a text file. The values for class name and attributes should come from database

Tags: vb.net

I want to create an executable that will use a text file as a template and create a class in vb.net
The class name and its attributes are stored in the database. The user should be able to input the class name. The ClassName and AttributeName tags in the template are to be replaced by the corresponding values from the database.
Any lead would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Maybe [`CodeDom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Code files are just text files. Generating code files is a bit confusing because you have source code appearing as string literals, but in a technical sense it isn't very difficult:

```
  Sub GenerateCode()
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    dtb.Columns.Add("ClassName")
    dtb.Columns.Add("PropertyName")
    dtb.Columns.Add("PropertyType")
    'NOTE: datatable must be sorted by ClassName
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassOne", "PropertyOne", "String")
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassOne", "PropertyTwo", "Integer")
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassOne", "PropertyThree", "String")
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassTwo", "AnotherPropertyOne", "String")
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassTwo", "AnotherPropertyTwo", "Integer")
    dtb.Rows.Add("ClassTwo", "AnotherPropertyThree", "String")

    Dim strFilename As String = ""
    Dim strParentFolder As String = "C:\Junk"
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(strParentFolder) Then
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strParentFolder)
    End If
    Dim strPreviousClassName As String = ""
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each drwProperty As DataRow In dtb.Rows
      Dim strThisClassName As String = drwProperty("ClassName").ToString
      If strThisClassName <> strPreviousClassName Then
        'class name has changed
        If strPreviousClassName > "" Then
          'write previous class
          sb.AppendLine("End Class")
          strFilename = strParentFolder & "\" & strPreviousClassName & ".vb"
          My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(strFilename, sb.ToString, False)
        End If
        'start new class
        sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("Class " & strThisClassName)
        strPreviousClassName = strThisClassName
      End If
      'append property
      sb.AppendLine("  Property " & drwProperty("PropertyName").ToString & " As " & drwProperty("PropertyType").ToString)
    Next drwProperty
    'Write last class
    sb.AppendLine("End Class")
    strFilename = strParentFolder & "\" & strPreviousClassName & ".vb"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(strFilename, sb.ToString, False)
  End Sub
```